# c++ (fstream w/r)Using inheritence, is the derived class actually two classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, fstream

Im  a bit confused. When I create a derived class, I get the constructor and destructor of the parent class. This, in my mind, would mean that I create 2 classes instead of one.

Now if i want to write the object to a file with fstream for example, using:

```
file.write((char*)&DerivedClass, sizeof(&DerivedClass));
```

Would that mean that i only write whatever is between the constructor and destructor of the derived class?

Yes, i tried typing it out myself, but i get mixed results. So thats why I am confused.
I hope someone could explain the mechanics behind it, and not so much a solution to writing it correctly.

Comment: No, methods is not data. When compiled, the data of an object and the functions of the object is two completely separate things.

Comment: You probably need to read about serialization. Writing out the data to file like that is rarely a good idea.

Comment: So if I am correct, the functions might be seperate on creation and destruction of the object, but the veriables and all its data would be a "Full Package" by passing it in a the write function of fstream?

Comment: Thx @TedLyngmo I will definitely do that! This already seemed very doubious. But you gotta learn step by step :) Cant make a car engine without knowing how combustion works :D

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the first part but for the second part, it depends on what you mean with "full package". You'll not get any data that is pointed out by pointers etc. If you have `std::string`s etc. this will fail. Also, if you write out different `int`:s and `float`:s and try to read this file on a different computer it may fail too because of endian issues.

Comment: Well, I know that normally I can pass any variable from an object, trough an object trough a function or method. However, when i use the code given above. I read it like this: copy whatver address you are pointing  at, and keep writing untill you get to the end of the object. But does it read from the constructor of the parent class or that from the derived class

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, because the constructor is totally separate from the object.

Comment: "_copy whatver address you are pointing at, and keep writing untill you get to the end of the object_", yes, that sounds about right, so you'll probably get very strange results when reading back objects from the file (unless you only use fundamental types - and read it back on a machine with the same architechture). The constructor of neither the parent nor child has anything to do with this.

Comment: Haha it starts to make sense, thanks for this sparring session :)